# Medical care for foreign national in US

Tags: visas

My neighbor had company in the US from Colombia. They incurred hospital bills that they never paid. My neighbor is wondering if the US can deny his family's visitor visas the next time they visit?

Comment: What does "company in the US from Columbia" mean?

Comment: Was it the neighbor's family that didn't pay the bills or did he sponsor them? The question has been edited to what we think the situation is. Please let us know if I've misinterpreted OR roll back the change.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica "Company" in the sense of household guests.

Comment: @choster Thanks! I just couldn't see it.

Answer (score 3):

No, immigration doesn't care.

When you take medical services in the US, you are taking them from a doctor or hospital, which is either a private person or business, or a non-profit charity.  With rare exception, they are not run by the US government.  Whoever they are, they bill you for the medical care, at "retail" (rich foreigner) rates.  That varies between "perfectly reasonable" (doctor) to "insane" ($15,000 for a $400 dialysis treatment).  To be honest, they don't expect the bill to be paid in full, and it can often be settled for far less. (if you paid $400 on that dialysis bill, they're happy).

All that to say, it's a very different situation than, say, the United Kingdom; where the government (NHS) pays for all  healthcare and that can influence immigration.

It is certainly a doctrine of the US government that we don't want you coming to our country and flinging yourself onto public services like welfare or food stamps. But since healthcare is largely in private hands, the government will not know or care about a hospital bill outstanding from private parties.

Comment: US medical _providers_ are almost all private, as you say, but _part_ of the cost of 'uncompensated care' is covered by various government programs; see https://www.kff.org/report-section/the-uninsured-and-the-aca-a-primer-key-facts-about-health-insurance-and-the-uninsured-amidst-changes-to-the-affordable-care-act-what-are-the-financial-implications-of-lacking-insu/ . Concur immigration (still) doesn't care.